# Trouble Reshaping Nd-array

Tags: python, numpy

I am working in Python and I have an image array which is of shape [100,3,200,1200]. The array is of format Number_of_images x Channels x Height x Width.  I want to split the images along the width direction into 6 images of shape 200x200 and add that as different channels. Ultimately, I would like to receive an array of shape [100,18,200,200].

I've attempted use the reshape function but it is not working as expected. I tried the following:

```py
np.reshape([100,18,200,200])
```

When I plot each image, I notice that it is not cropping the image the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First reshape to make the splits:

```
a = np.reshape(a, (100, 3, 200, 6, 200))
```

Then move the split axis besides the channel axis:

```
a = np.moveaxis(a, 3, 2)
```

Then merge those two axes:

```
a = np.reshape(a, (100, 18, 200, 200))
```

In this case, the 18 channels would be sorted as:

```
[red-split1, red-split2, red-split3, red-split4, red-split5, red-split6,
 green-split1, ..., green-split6,
 blue-split1, ..., blue-split6]
```

If you change the second instruction to:

```
a = np.moveaxis(a, 3, 1)
```

The axes would be sorted as:

```
[red-split1, green-split1, blue-split1,
 ...,
 red-split6, green-split6, blue-split6]
```

Comment: While this is of course fine from a correctness point of view, note that it may or may not be desirable from a performance point of view. The first `reshape` and the `moveaxis` (or transpose, of which moveaxis is a special case) don't need any changes to the layout of the values in memory, so their results are just views into the original array and the operations perform very quickly. However, the second `reshape`, due to the preceding swizzling of the axes, cannot preserve the order of the items in memory and so must create a copy of the data, which can be slow for big arrays.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Yes, thanks for pointing that out. It is indeed a significant copy, ~70MB if chhanels are one byte and ~275MB if they are four bytes. I don't think there is a way to avoid the copy if we want to achieve the requested shape, though.

Comment: You're correct, it's not possible with the data as presented in the question while retaining Numpy semantics. However, if it's an option to start out with a different shape where the width is next to the channels from the get-go, this would be possible. For instance `(no_img, channels, width, height)` or `(no_img, height, width, channels)`.